# allow a user to run command as another user without any password prompt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, sudo

I'm trying to achieve same result [as the answer from that existing SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access) without having to enter the password for the original user, that is, I'm `userA`, and I want to be able to run a command as `userB` without having to enter the passwords for any of these users.

**Can somehow provide an example to assist me please?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `NOPASSWD` tag. So, using the example in the previous question, you would do:

```
tom  ALL=(oracle) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown tom *
```