# How can I create an “su” only user (no SSH or SFTP) and limit who can “su” into that account in RHEL5?

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5, sudo, su

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I allow one user to su to another without allowing root access?](https://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access)

We have a user account that our DBAs use (`oracle`). I do not want to set a password on this account and want to only allow users in the `dba` group to `su - oracle`.

How can I accomplish this?

I was thinking of just giving them `sudo` access to the `su - oracle` command. However, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a more polished/elegant/secure way.

Comment: Think the answer here would apply: http://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access

Comment: Thanks @JamesYale, different "problem" but seems to answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to give them full access to the user account anyway, why not just let them do whatever they want via `sudo` directly?

```
%dba     ALL = (oracle) ALL
```

This line in `sudoers` will allow anyone in the `dba` user group to run any command as the `oracle` user, including getting a shell with either `sudo -su oracle` or `sudo -iu oracle` for a login shell.

Alternatively, if you don't want them to have access to everything, you can substitute the last `ALL` with a list of commands to limit them to, eg.

```
%dba     ALL = (oracle) /bin/chmod, /usr/local/bin/oracleclient localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Use

```
sudo -u oracle -i
```

and add permissions for nopasswd default shell like:

```
%dba    ALL=(oracle)NOPASSWD: /bin/bash
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why limit them to a shell? Seems an odd command to pick to limit to since once they have a shell they can run anything anyway.

Comment: @MatthewScharley limiting to a shell is enough to execute `sudo -i`.  Furthermore, OP asked to limit just to `su - oracle`. Though you always can replace `/bin/bash` to `ALL`. =)